# Присоединить один столбец из другого DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

Всем привет
есть две таблицы
пишу в панде функцию 
`df = df.merge(input_sku, how='inner', on='KEY1')`

однако из второй таблицы мне нужен только один столбец.
Как это указать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проще всего - оставить в присоединяемом DataFrame только нужные столбцы - столбец(ы), учавствующий(е) в объединении и столбец, который вы хотите присоединить:

```
df = df.merge(input_sku[['KEY1','data_column_name']], on='KEY1')
```